# while automating the slider, The slider moves only when i placed my mouse over it in selenium

Tags: selenium

http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=5&controller=category#/

This is my code,whats wrong with it?

```
By locator = By.cssSelector(".ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-state-hover");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        WebElement sliderRight = driver.findElement(locator);
        action.dragAndDropBy(sliderRight,-40,0).build().perform();
        action.moveToElement(sliderRight).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: You try the following code action.moveToElement(sliderRight).dragAndDropBy(sliderRight,-40,0).build().perform

Comment: actually i have used the above code .the draganddrop line executes only when i manually points the mouse over the element

Comment: @kowshikgowtham Can you consider updating us your exact manual steps and the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where's actions taking under consideration the driver.
Try to enter the following code,

```
Actions action=new Actions(WebDriver);
```

Comment: actually i have used the above code .the draganddrop line executes only when i manually points the mouse over the element.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a wrong cssSelector. I have modified your code and it should work now.

**Here is the java code**

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/chromedriver 3");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=5&controller=category#/");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

  //modified the css selector
    By locator = By.cssSelector(".ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all"); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    WebElement sliderRight = driver.findElement(locator);
    action.dragAndDropBy(sliderRight,70,0).build().perform();
    action.moveToElement(sliderRight).click().build().perform();
```